# How to create bootable sd card from different img files

Tags: android, adb, odroid, fastboot, bootable

I have built cyanogenmod lollipop source for odroid-xu4 SBC and resulted into separate image files like system.img, boot.img, cache.img, kernel, ramdisk.img, ramdisk-recovery.img, recovery.img, userdata.img and other folders like install, root, system etc.

How do I make bootable sd card from these images?  There are methods where we can write image to sd card using dd in linux or Win32DiskImager in windows but these tools require single image files and these tools might be extracting system, boot kernel images etc from single .img file. But since I am directly having extracted images, how do I achieve it?

Is the process board dependent, I mean do I need to worry about where exactly in memory space different images are written? There is guide given at [write image to odroid-xu4](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:xu3_building_android) but it talks about pushing images to sdcard using adb. This means I need other android image previously flashed?

Comment: http://newandroidbook.com/tools/imgtool.html

Comment: This didn't help. This tool is more of extraction rather than combining or dumping images.